# Bootstrap dropdown doesn't work in jhipster

Tags: angular, jhipster, bootstrap-4

```
<div class="form-group">
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown
                        Example
                        <span class="caret"></span></button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
```

In the default home.html I have added that code to display a dropdown. But that was not displayed the values inside the box when I clicked. So how to make it workable?

Comment: There a library called jhipster now?! I just read the jhipster tag information and I'm still mystified. I guess I'm just not hip enough.

Comment: Actually JHipster is a free and open-source application generator used to develop quickly a modern web application and Microservices using Angular and the Spring Framework according to given definition. I am very new it. That's why I need help

Comment: Did you using angularjs or angular 2 ?? In your jhipster app

Comment: Well first of all you need to learn to use the F12 debugger. Check the console and see if any errors popped up. Also right click / inspect element and see if your <li> are in there but hidden

Comment: angularjs 1 @Chandru

Comment: already debugged. They were empty. @Nick.McDermaid

Comment: So when you inspected the element you could see the <ul class> tag, but inside it were there <li> elements or not? If not, that would make me think either the source isn't what you think it is (press CTRL-F5 to force a refresh), or something is actively removing them (highly unlikely)

Comment: Check my answer. i will updated it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in angularjs :

Updated my Answer in below

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div uib-dropdown class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" uib-dropdown-toggle type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown
            Example
            <span class="caret"></span></button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" uib-dropdown-menu>
            <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: After installing your above mentioned bootstrap module can't execute gulp command even reinstall gulp. Maybe some packages were removing once execute above command to install bootstrap

Comment: Sorry I mean your using angular 2 this answer for angular 2 above version

Comment: I will updated my answers. i hope this a way to solution for your question

Answer (score 1):

I'm using jhipster 6.0.1 (angular 7.2.12 with bootstrap 4.3.1) and was having the same problem.

The 'issue' here is that jhipster **does not use plain old bootstrap**, it uses [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/), 4.1.1 in my case.
You can see a sample of how to use the dropdown in the entities menu from the `navbar.component.html` file, where they've used `ngbDropdown`, `ngbDropdownToggle` and `ngbDropdownMenu` directives. Or, you can use any sample provided in the ng-bootstrap [dropdown documentation](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/dropdown/examples), i.e.

```html
<div class="btn-group mr-3">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Split me</button>
  <div class="btn-group" ngbDropdown role="group" aria-label="Button group with nested dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle-split" ngbDropdownToggle></button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" ngbDropdownMenu>
      <button ngbDropdownItem>One</button>
      <button ngbDropdownItem>Two</button>
      <button ngbDropdownItem>Four!</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

below is the working example from bootstap website , you dont have to use ul/li for the list ,

```
<div class="dropdown">
<button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" 
 id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-
 expanded="false">
 Dropdown button
 </button>
<div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That also doesn't work. I have tried several options to create bootstrap dropdowns. Maybe jhipster we need to configure another file. But still couldn't get it.